# CORS Policy Blocking Java Spring API Request calling from React using axios

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, axios, cors

I have a gateway with some APIs developed with Java Spring boot. But when I am calling the APIs from my react project the below error is thrown.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8081/testgw/hello' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have added the @CrossOrigin annotation to my rest controller as below.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins= {"*"}, maxAge = 4800, allowCredentials = "false" )
@RestController
public class FTController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String getHello() {    
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

And I am calling the API from my react project as below

```
var url = "http://localhost:8081/testgw/hello";
axios.get(url, {
    headers: {
        'Authorization' : 'Basic [AuthKey]',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT'
    }
})
.then(
    function(response) {
        console.log("response --> " + response);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
);
```

I am not getting rid of this problem. Please let me know what should I do to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

After a lots of struggling I am able to get rid of this issue. Generally adding the `@CrossOrigin` annotation over the REST controller class the request methods should fix the issue.

But if adding the annotation doesn't solve the issue then it's generating from your browser. In that case you can overcome the issue by running the browser disabling the web security.

For windows you can run goggle chrome disabling the web security by following the below steps

1. Open run (Press **Window Key + R**)
2. Write the below command

   **chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security**
3. Press Enter